# use a webbased datafile with SET !DATASOURCE

Tags: imacros

How can i use a webbased file ie csv file like [csv file link](http://hakikahost.com/css/profile1.csv) with the `SET !DATASOURCE` command in imacros,the reason is that i want to use the webbased file?

Answer (score 1):

```
SET !DATASOURCE profile1.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 4
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOOP}}


TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=CLASS:textbox1 CONTENT={{!COL0}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=CLASS:textbox2 CONTENT={{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=CLASS:textbox3 CONTENT={{!COL2}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=CLASS:textbox4 CONTENT={{!COL3}}
```

This example reads CSV file from Hard Drive placed in Datasource folder. As for webased file the only idea I have right now is if you had something like a sheet in the web browser window. From it iMacros can read the whole table and use those data . But without JS scripting it can't be done easily.

Answer (score 0):

Make an iMacros code that downloads that file from a webserver to your hard drive/datasource folder.